# How do I append a row to an empty Dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am iterating over rows in a dataframe to see if an image is not found on a server. If it's not found, then it removes the row from the dataframe and makes a new CSV file. I would like to take that row that contains the image not found on the server and append it to a new dataframe that will create a new CSV that we can investigate why an image is not found. I can successfully remove the row from the original dataframe, but appending the new row to the new dataframe results in an empty dataframe once run. How might I solve this

```
filename2 = 'images_not_found.csv'
orders_csv = pd.read_csv(path + filename)
not_found_images = pd.DataFrame()


for index, row in orders_csv.iterrows():
    if not os.path.isfile(row['Image']):
        orders_csv.drop(index, inplace=True)
        not_found_images.append(row, ignore_index=True)

orders_csv.to_csv(path + filename, index=False)
not_found_images.to_csv(path + filename2, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a list, [`df.append(new_df)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) doesn't append inline, meaning doesn't add `new_df` to `df`. You need to define `df` again:

```
df = df.append(new_df)
```

In your code:

```
not_found_images = not_found_images.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might sound confusing, but the *append* method of pandas DataFrame doesn't work in place. You have to re-assign the resulting Dataframe to your variable.

```
not_found_images = not_found_images.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting my solution.